# Working with objects in MySql

Tags: mysql, plsql

I am working with the pl/sql objects in MySql workbench. I tried to run the following script :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE address AS OBJECT
(house_no varchar2(10),
street varchar2(30),
city varchar2(20),
state varchar2(10),
pincode varchar2(10)
);
```

But I am getting this error : `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE address AS OBJECT (house_no varchar2(10),  street varchar2(30),  city varch' at line 1`

THNX in advance !

Answer (score 1):

pl/sql is Oracle only, it isn't supported by MySQL. MySQL doesn't support custom types.